# Where can I find the COPY-ed artifact from a previous build stage?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am experimenting with [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) and started with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:latest AS build
ENV GO111MODULE on
ENV GOOS linux
WORKDIR /build
ADD main.go .
RUN go mod init caddy
RUN go build

FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /build/caddy ./caddy
CMD "./caddy"
```

The build log looks good:

```
Step 1/11 : FROM golang:latest AS build
 ---> a1072a078890
Step 2/11 : ENV GO111MODULE on
 ---> Running in 15d89fe6e4f4
Removing intermediate container 15d89fe6e4f4
 ---> d65cead90351
Step 3/11 : ENV GOOS linux
 ---> Running in 9ee1c730bd2e
Removing intermediate container 9ee1c730bd2e
 ---> 98cbf8d9ff94
Step 4/11 : WORKDIR /build
 ---> Running in 8cf4b491df08
Removing intermediate container 8cf4b491df08
 ---> cabdb71ef8f2
Step 5/11 : ADD main.go .
 ---> d6e01c42a24c
Step 6/11 : RUN go mod init caddy
 ---> Running in 9718a450ccb7
go: creating new go.mod: module caddy
Removing intermediate container 9718a450ccb7
 ---> 290f25973b0a
Step 7/11 : RUN go build
 ---> Running in 8f65e4d02d1c
go: finding github.com/pyed/ipfilter v1.1.4
go: finding github.com/aablinov/caddy-geoip latest
(... successful "finding", "downloading" steps ...)
go: finding gopkg.in/tomb.v1 v1.0.0-20141024135613-dd632973f1e7
go: finding gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1 v1.4.7
Removing intermediate container 8f65e4d02d1c
 ---> eb63824b8795

Step 8/11 : FROM alpine:latest
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
63bc94deeb28: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:7c92a2c6bbcb6b6beff92d0a940779769c2477b807c202954c537e2e0deb9bed
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
 ---> c85b8f829d1f
Step 9/11 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in 1099076a5e16
Removing intermediate container 1099076a5e16
 ---> 419bb0ef875e
Step 10/11 : COPY --from=build /build/caddy ./caddy
 ---> 49213be447ce
Step 11/11 : CMD "./caddy"
 ---> Running in 6a91d4783d8b
Removing intermediate container 6a91d4783d8b
 ---> 940b1494793b

Successfully built 940b1494793b
Successfully tagged caddy-docker-proxy:latest
Creating container...
Container Id: eeda1a1bd57e19180b664376546b3128ed28c9ff37317c013829faae4a859978
Container name: 'caddy-docker-proxy'
Attaching to container 'caddy-docker-proxy'...
Starting container 'caddy-docker-proxy'
```

The image does not start, though, because

```
/bin/sh: ./caddy: not found
```

I thought that the step

```
Step 10/11 : COPY --from=build /build/caddy ./caddy
 ---> 49213be447ce
```

meant that the copy was successful. Otherwise there would have been an error about not finding the artifact to copy (I guess)

I tried `COPY --from=build /build/caddy ./caddy` and/or to start via `CMD "/app/caddy"` but the error is the same.

**Where is `caddy` from the first build?**

Comment: One of the things that makes Alpine images smaller is that they don't have most of the shared libraries that a full-blown distro has.  If you run a tool like `ldd` on the final binary, are all of its dependencies there?

Comment: @DavidMaze You are right, I did not think about that. Can you please put your comment into an answer do that I can accept it and add to it a working `Dockerfile` and some extra explanation and links?

Comment: @DavidMaze is right. But you can create totally static Go build -> you can build your Docker image from `scratch` = no problems with dynamically linked libraries + you will reduce attack surface -> better security.